# Nextjs API Removing Cookie Success But Deployed on Netlify Removing Failed

Tags: node.js, cookies, next.js, netlify

### Overview

Hi, I am building a webapp using `Nextjs`, `Firebase Authentication`, `Firestore`, `ChakraUI`.

### Problem

For the authentication, I stored the `uid` of user into cookie through the api. Here is the code

/api/auth/login

```js
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  const { loginWithEmailAndPassword } = AuthService;
  try {
    const userCredential = await loginWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    if (!userCredential.user) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error:
          "[Firebase Authentication] : userCredential exist but does not have user property "
      });
    }
    const uid = userCredential.user.uid;
    res.setHeader(
      "set-cookie",
      `uid=${uid}; Max-Age=${1000 * 60 * 24 * 14};Path=/; HttpOnly`
    );

    return res.status(200).json({ uid: userCredential.user.uid });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return res
      .status(500)
      .json({ error: "[NextJs] : Backend API Login Failed" });
  }
}
```

And when user logout, I will remove the cookie at the below api.
/api/auth/logout.ts

```js
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const { logout } = AuthService;
  try {
    await logout();
    res.setHeader(
      "set-cookie",
      `uid=deleted; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;Path=/; HttpOnly`
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("user logout failed");
    return res.status(500).json({ error: e });
  }

  return res.status(200).json({ message: "Logout success" });
}
```

**Everything works will on local `npm run dev`.**

**But when I deploy my project on `Netlify`, the cookie could be added but cannot be removed.**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might be pushed .env file to the GitHub that's why this error may occur.